# Rescript plugin rescript-vscode non working after a fresh install

Tags: visual-studio-code, rescript

New to rescript, i've done all steps specified in the [getting started](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/installation) page and furthermore installed the [visual studio code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chenglou92.rescript-vscode) but as I try to edit neither completion nor error highlighting works.

I've tried all steps on the plugin gif but if i can populate the first line for the rest nothing is working the same.

I don't know which file to pass you for exploring the configuration but it's exactly the same as in the getting started template repo.

Comment: Dumb question: Did you save your file? You only get diagnostics after saving (at least for now).
If you however still want instant feedback, you can get it with this workaround: https://forum.rescript-lang.org/t/easy-workaround-in-rescript-vscode-for-instant-error-reporting/743

Comment: Yep I did save the file
I will try what you suggest when I have a moment
Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

Really stupid error on my part - did forgot to run `yarn install`